# how to mock NpgsqlTransaction and NpgsqlConnection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, npgsql

I am currently trying to write unittest for method such as this

```
    public bool SaveSchema(Schema newSchema, NpgsqlTransaction transaction)
```

and the properties being parsed the method is a Schema, and a NpgsqlTransaction  transaction.
The schema can easily be generated, as it code I have full access to but the transaction is a bit of a different story.

I cannot seem to figure out a good way of mocking this?

I tried writing wrapper for it, but NpgsqlTransaction don't have a public constructor, so
it is not possible to make one, or I end up writing the entire thing twice

here is my attempt - isn't there no better way of mocking the NpgsqlTransaction?

```
   public class NpgsqlConnectionAdapter : INpgsqlConnectionAdapter
    {
        private readonly NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConnection;

        public NpgsqlConnectionAdapter()
        {
            npgsqlConnection = new();
        }

        public NpgsqlTransaction BeginTransaction()
        {
            return npgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public void Commit()
        {

        }

    }

    public class NpgsqlTransactionAdapter : INpgsqlTransactionAdapter
    {

        private readonly NpgsqlTransaction npgsqlTransaction;

        public void Commit()
        {
            npgsqlTransaction.Commit();
        }

    }

    public interface INpgsqlConnectionAdapter
    {

    }

    public interface INpgsqlTransactionAdapter
    {

    }
```

Comment: Just don't do this. You want integration tests against a real database to test this stuff, then you should have a layer over this that you test in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking your database is a huge effort and probably worthless in the end. You will find that you spent more time on mocking extremely complicated things and you gain nothing, because you still don't know if your actual statements would really work on a real database.

The way to go here is to write your database layer as technology agnostic as possible. For example, you should use `IDbConnection` and `IDbTransaction` in your code and only have single point where you actually decide that it's a `NpgsqlConnection` with a specific connection string in production.

That way for your unit tests you only need to change a single line, and tell it to (for example) use an Sqlite in-memory database instead. Now you can unit test with a real database, but one that is self-contained to this test only.

Comment: So i should change the method to be something like this 
    `public bool SaveSchema(Schema newSchema, DbTransaction transaction)`
?

and rewrite the entire code to now use it?

I mean I am using a alot built-in npgsql stuf..
Like creating a NpgsqlCommand from an NpgsqlTransaction and etc.

Comment: @IamnotFat Well, you didn't give me a lot to work with... `public bool SaveSchema(Schema newSchema, IDbTransaction transaction)`.

Comment: I would suspect that the build-in npgsql stuff conforms to the conventions and you can safely replace it. It takes a little while to get used to it, for example you no longer create commands by saying "new NpgsqlCommand" but instead you use the CreateCommand from the connection. This way, you can reduce your dependencies down to one actual line, instead of scattering them all over your code.

Comment: The only problem would be if you had used Npgsql dependent SQL commands (real SQL inside a text in C# that you pass to a command) that would not run on other SQL databases. But maybe it would be better to not do that anyway.

Comment: IDbConnection and IDbTransaction should be avoided - these are old interfaces which haven't been updated over the years (because doing so would have broken existing drivers). For example, they do not contains any async APIs. Use DbConnection and DbTransaction instead for mocking purposes.

Comment: Good catch, I agree, if both your original driver and your test driver support it, DbConnection and DbTransaction would be the better choice.

Comment: But how would you mock DbConnection and DbTransaction, aren't interfaces only mockable?

Comment: You don't mock them. That is the whole point. You simply switch your production database server for a very lightweight in-memory database like Sqlite in your tests. It's still a real database, not a bunch of hacked database fakes.